# How to approach: Write a Windows application that accepts any number of positive values

Tags: c#

How should I approach this assignment? Should I use an if/else statement?

Assignment 1:

Write a Windows application that accepts any number of positive values.
The user clicks a button to process all the inputted data at any time. The resulting output:

1. sum of all the n entered numbers, followed by n rows, displayed in the order of input:
2. the original inputted number;
3. the percentage contributed by this number to the sum.

Comment: There's much more to it than an `if..else` statement. Have you not learned basic C# in your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't understand the project in entirety. This should at least point you in a solid direction.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Select C#
3. Choose Windows Form Application

At this point your project will open with a canvas, in designer mode.  To help describe what is happening `click` the `Form` once.

On the right-hand side of your Window you will see `Solution Explorer` and `Properties`.

Solution Explorer: This will show you the contents of your project.  It contains the following:

- Properties: `Assembly`, `Resource`, and `Settings` information.
- References: This will contain all your project references, `Assemblies` that help expand your project or link to other applications you may be doing.

The next item, is going to be your `Form`.  This is the most important part; because this will be where all your manipulation will be.

Now the second item I mentioned; `Properties`.  Not the one in `Solution Explorer` but the tab that stands apart.  Will show you all the modifications for that component.  In this case, your `Form`.

On the left-hand side what you'll do is actually go to `Toolbox`.  These are all the components that Microsoft provides you right out of the gate.  Simply drag the `Textbox` Component out of the `Toolbox` onto your `Form` (canvas).

You'll notice the outline, with several `transformation` dots for you to manipulate location and dimensions.

Before we move further I'll break it down what has happened.  You've input a blank `textbox` onto your `Form`.  By default it will be called `TextBox1`.  It is good practice to identify the component with what it is then it's desired function. If your looking for lets say a users first name, name it `txtFirst`.  That way it is easier to understand what your manipulating.

Since my goal is to help point you in the right direction, follow these steps:

1. Drag a `Label`- Name it `lblInput` (Change text to name of your choice).
2. Drag out a `Textbox`- Name it `txtInput`.
3. Drag out a `Rich Textbox` - Name it `rtxtDisplay`.

Now these three components will inherently be your `User Interface`. All of the interaction will occur here.  But we are missing one `Element` to the interface.  A button, this is important because it will create what is called an `Event`.  These will essentially notify the interface of a change so it appears that it is doing something.

- Drag a `Button` out of the Toolbox, name is `btnAdd`.

Now you have an entire interface; so now double click on the button.  Your screen will now change; you'll see all of this text.

The important part is where it navigated you to by selecting the button.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Implementation Here.
}
```

So that will provide you the `Event` so you can perform your logic to create your application.  Now, I'm not going to do your code for you.  But I'll do something close so you can adapt and learn.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Method One: "Casting"
    // By default txtInput is a String, you require integers.  So you can add.
    /* So you would want to ensure proper Error Handling exists, otherwise when you cast you'll receive an invalid cast exception. */
    txtInput.Text = (int)data;
}
```

So as you can see the `//` and `/*` are different methods to comment to make your logic easy to understand.  I'm using it to explain what is happening for you.  The `txtInput.Text` takes whatever input `string` value and is now being `casted` to an `integer`.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Method Two: "Array"
     int[] data;
}
```

Now, this will actually allocate a reference in your memory.  Which will allow you to store multiple things into the `Array`.  This method would work well if you pass all your `textbox` input into your `Rich Textbox`.  Then a second button could fill the array to add each item.

In this example I will actually write an entire aspect but as I stated you'll need to do certain things to make it meet your needs.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   // Create Storage
   List<string> store = new List<string>();

   private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Will add the input of the textbox to list each time button clicked.
       store.Add(textbox1.Text);
   }

   private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Logic to Add the items.
   }
}
```

There is half your battle right there.  Things to help you truly understand this conceptually, will be these items to help you complete your project.

- `Casting`
- `Arrays`
- `Generics`
- `Loops`

Hopefully that helps you.  Those are some basic lessons; I might suggest the entry level tutorial courses on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `textbox` to prompt for values.
2. Create two `buttons`. `ProcessButton` for processing values up to now and `INPUT` button for taking the user input (could also use a `key event handler` if you prefer pressing `ENTER` after typing the value in textbox)
3. As values are being entered in the textbox store them in a `List<int>` or whatever depending on your problem.
4. When `ProcessButton` is pressed then call `List<int>.Sum()` and print the value
5. Print each item in the `List<int>` using `foreach` statement.
6. Continue from here